How come I'm banned for asking bad questions when I've never asked any questions or given any answers?
That's right, no questions, no answers, and banned for it.
SOMEHOW, y'all will explain this away by blaming the computer. And you'll swear it's reasonable and fair.
If past is truly prologue, I'll get permanently banned for even asking about this. I used to think Stack Exchange was elite scientists. But it's just bullies like Reddit.
Y'all tell the computer to kick out people you don't like, or you manually lower the credits so they can't participate,  then you blame "the algorithm."

You did ask a couple of bad questions, so bad they got not just closed, but deleted. That's why they don't show up in your question totals any more. One was about whether it was a good idea to send a rap song to space using the DSN or some such. Don't remember the other.

So, to sum up, the premise of this post ("I've never asked any questions") is completely false. You did in fact ask questions. Based on the evidence, it appears that you do in fact know how to do something other than tell the truth.

This is not a question asked in good faith. You have asked questions not suitable for this site that were heavily downvoted by the community as a whole. It is not good behaviour to then create a meta post lying about that. It is also not acceptable behaviour to be rude and aggressive to folks who provide constructive comments.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Your first question explicitly called for opinions, in contravention of site rules.  After it got downvotes, you commented

Downvotes? Downvotes? If I cared about money, I'd name names, quote the dead, and sell that to Wired, ya bastids!

The name-calling is when I voted to delete.  I can't speak for the other two people who so-voted, obviously.
Your second question was also an explicit appeal to opinion, after you'd already been directed to What types of questions should I avoid asking? in the comments to the previous question. It got downvoted and closed because it was against the rules. You complained about it being closed and said of the site

I used to think of stack exchange as being the elite science site, but it's not for real either. It's just another Reddit.

More name-calling, and so I voted to delete again.  Along with two others.
We have a little community here.  We may be overly-insular or rule-adherent; we've had a lot of discussions about if and how we should be more welcoming. But why should we tolerate abuse?

I was hoping to attract people who believed strongly one way or the other. That would have been interesting. Then I realized I was betrayed again by the normal people. Y'all can shittify anything. You take something good and interesting, forcibly misinterpret my motivation, and turn it into something shitty.

Interesting to whom?  Not to us--and not all of us would be "normal people" by the definition I believe you're using (I'm not neurotypical, for example). We laid out our rules in advance. You can meet us halfway.
